# Adding elements to xml - breaking axis2 stub

Tags: java, xml, soap, apache-axis, wsdl2java

We have a partner that hosts a service that we consume. We generally use Axis2 to generate our proxy/stub classes. The problem is that any time they add new elements to the wsdl, we are receiving an AxisFault:

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {https://foo.bar.com} NewElement

Is there a way for us to make it so newly added elements do not break our implementation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: also we tried adding -Eiu to the wsdl2java command, and it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem by:
1. Download Axis2 1.6.2-Release binary distribution and source distribution;
2. Follow the bug-fix pages to change the source code in source distribution. 
   The pages are:
   https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12457689/iu_trunk.patch
   https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12518906/patch.txt
3. Rebuild the adb-codegen and codegen module to get axis2-adb-codegen-1.6.2.jar and axis2-codegen-1.6.2.jar;
4. Replace these two jars in lib of binary distribution path;
5. Finally run the command with -Eiu to generate stub code.